# How to use "tagged" type to index a record?

Tags: typescript

This is how I tag my identifiers:

```
type Id<Tag extends string> = string & {__tag: Tag};
type UserId = Id<'UserId'>;
```

But I'm not able to use them when they index records:

```
type Users = Record<UserId, User>;
type FirstName = {[k in keyof Users]: Users[k]['firstName']}[keyof Users];
```

It fails with:

> TS2538: Type 'Id<"UserId">' cannot be used as an index type.

Suggestions?

[Here's a playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJgHgCoEMDmUIA9gQHZwDOUhwATgJZ5oB8UAvCeVRgGRQDeA%20l8OgFxRUaAL4BuALAAoUJCgBVQhDLwGsRAHJFy%20BpqSZ4aNrLFGAJQgBjAPZlEJ%20ABoFSsvumzoAMQqngAHIoALbQjBwA2gDWUFRQURAgNgBmrsqEALqCJoTRGSLRiSlpphkG0hWGciZqHBRw2W7OUMl%20pEGhgqSU1C4ANijtIRBdzNTiQA)

Comment: `keyof Users` will not return union type of keys, because `User` type has indexed key.
Try in Playground `type UsersKeys = keyof Record<string, User>; // string type itself`
TS is unable to get user ID's  list from runtime

Comment: It looks like branded primitives were not intended to be key types, so you are probably out of luck here.  Widen `Users` to `Record<string, User>` and do some other type guard to narrow the key to `UserId` if you need the compiler to notice it, maybe?

Comment: Or maybe switch to something like `Map<UserId, User>` instead of trying to use keyof/lookup types?  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/qWJKlw) for example.  If any of this seems like an answer to you I'd be happy to write it up.

Comment: @jcalz `Map` is the shizzle! Shed us the light, please : )

Comment: @jcalz one problem I found about `Map` in meantime, is that it doesn't automatically serialize (`JSON.stringify`) :/ It's fine if you're done writing up the answer, but if not, I'd rather squat on this a while longer.

Comment: You could fairly easily write serialization/deserialization for a `Map`.  But yes, `Map` is just one of the possible workarounds.  I haven't written it up yet so I'll wait.

Comment: @jcalz I got structures in which this Map would be 3 levels deep, so it implies a lot of work around itself. I'd rather not : )

Comment: It's not that branded primitives weren't intended to be used as key types @jcalz - it's just that arbitrary index types are not yet supported (but they're on the possible-roadmap for 4.2) https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41601 / https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797

Comment: And yet `symbol`-typed keys are supported without such arbitrary index types: `const s = Symbol.for("xyz"); type Foo = { [s]: 123; }`.  And also with enums: `enum E { A }; type Bar = { [E.A]: 456 };`  (which actually widens the enum)  It really feels to me that nobody ever said "yes, we should support allowing branded primitives as key types and make sure it works".  At least, looking around at GitHub issues, I don't see anyone mentioning using them as keys.  So the intent to support them as keys seems to be absent. Maybe arbitrary index signatures, if added, would support this, but maybe not?

Comment: @jcalz so from what i understand, symbols can be used to index records. If true, can they somehow be used to brand primitive identifiers like string or number?